# how convert array of numbers to array of char using python?

Tags: python

i want to convert array of numbers to character
Example:
Input[65,97,98,66]
Read ASCII code for each location
result
Output[A,a,b,B]

Comment: Use `chr(<int>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `chr` built-in function. A list comprehension should also be used:

```
l = [65,97,98,66]

print([chr(c) for c in l])
# ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B']
```